# Sitecore Role Based Visibility of Items

Tags: workflow, role-management

We need to have role-based visibility of items in the Content Tree where items created by Admins should not be visible to anybody apart from Admins and items created by Approvers can be visible to Admins but Authors can not see those items.

Can anybody suggest a solution for this?

Comment: You can deny read access on the items for these roles. This should hide them in the content tree. Check the documentation on access rights on how to do this: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/the-access-rights.html

Comment: Read access should only be denied if they are created by higher roles for example if Admin created then it should only be visible to admin if approver created then it should be visible to admin and not to content Authors

Comment: Have these items have special locations in content tree? Or they can be created anywhere by Admins or Approvers?

Comment: No the location is same for all the items